# jQuery, Get contents of a tag after a class

Tags: jquery

I need to get contents of a "b" tag and unfortunately I cannot change the html.

```
<div class="mw_error">

    // Sometimes "b" tags are inserted here and sometimes not

    <span class="loseText">
       <b> You Lost </b>
    </span>

    Text 1
    <b> Need to access this value </b>
    Text 2
    <b> Need to access this value </b>

</div>
```

I can get the correct contents of the "b" tags as long as those two "b".

The problem is that sometimes there are "b" tags inserted between the "span class lose Text" depending on the message returned.

I was wondering if it is possible to use jQuery to select the "b" tags after the span class "loseText". I have looked at the .after function but cant seem to get it to work.

Any help on this would be much appreciated :)

I forgot to say I need to only select the first two "b" tags after the span class.

Comment: Should the `<b>` tags preceding the `<span>` be caught too? or not?

Comment: No, I would like to just get the next two <b> tags after the <span> :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
$('.loseText').nextAll('b').slice(0, 2);
```

Edited to only select 2 (maximum)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var $b = $('.loseText ~ b');
if ($b.length) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aCQWe/)

To limit it to the 1st two tags, use:

```
var $b = $('.loseText ~ b:lt(2)');
```

[**See the demo for that.**](http://jsfiddle.net/aCQWe/1/)

Comment: How would could I limit it so only the first two <b> tags were selected?

Comment: Easy, and we don't need no stinking `slice`s either! ;) See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
$('.mw_error > b').each(...);
```

See the example. **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/GWF88/)**.

Comment: I think he's saying sometimes there are `.mw_error > b` tags he does not want to grab, between the top of the element and `.loseText`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use:

```
$('.loseText').children('b')
```

Comment: He's trying to get the siblings of `.loseText`, not the children.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
$("div.mw_error").children("b");
```

This shold get the `b` tags which are not within the `span.loseText`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".loseText").nextAll("b");
```